# Extract data from a compressed numpy masked array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to plot a compressed numpy masked array but I am having trouble in extracting only the data. For example, I have a compressed array

```
print z_masked.compressed
```

which gives me:

```
<bound method MaskedArray.compressed of masked_array(data = [0.0 0.012345679012345678 0.04938271604938271 0.1111111111111111
 0.19753086419753085 0.308641975308642 0.4444444444444444 -- -- --],
             mask = [False False False False False False False  True  True  True],
       fill_value = 1e+20)
>
```

but when I try to plot this as

```
plt.figure()
plt.plot(z_masked.compressed)
```

I get an error:

```
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number
```

due to the mask information. Can someone show me how to get around this? Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take another look at the output of your print statement:

```
<bound method MaskedArray.compressed of masked_array(...
```

`z_masked.compressed` is the **method** of the array that returns the non-masked data, not the data itself. You need to call it:

```
plt.plot(z_masked.compressed())
```